# Heroku horizontal vs vertical scaling and 1x vs 2x dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

A Standard 1x dyno on Heroku allows for 512MB of RAM. A Standard 2x dyno on Heroku allows for 1GB. Upgrading from a 1x dyno to a 2x dyno is referred to as vertical scaling, while adding more 1x dynos instead is referred to as horizontal scaling.

I believe horizontal scaling allows my app to service more http requests, but I'm not so sure what vertical scaling does.

Another thing that I don't think is too clear about Heroku: Does having 2 1x dynos still only provide 512MB of RAM total (instead of 512MB + 512MB)? If that is the case, how much RAM does my app have with 1 1x dyno and 1 2x dyno?

And after upgrading/downgrading the amount of dynos on Heroku's website, is there anything else that has to be done through the terminal to get them working?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe horizontal scaling allows my app to service more http
> requests, but I'm not so sure what vertical scaling does

Vertical Scaling increases the capacity of the existing hardware or software by adding resources. It can enhance your server, however, it is limited by the fact that you can only get as big as the size of the server.
Vertical scaling also improves the response time of the request and resulted in handling more HTTP requests.

> Another thing that I don't think is too clear about Heroku: Does
> having 2 1x dynos still only provide 512MB of RAM total (instead of
> 512MB + 512MB)? If that is the case, how much RAM does my app have
> with 1 1x dyno and 1 2x dyno?

2 1x dynos mean your code is running on two dynos, each has 512MB of ram.
Heroku load balancer will automatically distributes the requests to

> And after upgrading/downgrading the amount of dynos on Heroku's
> website, is there anything else that has to be done through the
> terminal to get them working?

No